# Multiple string replacements in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
line = input('Line: ')
if 'a' in line:
  print(line.replace('a', 'afa'))
elif 'e' in line:
  print(line.replace('e', 'efe'))
```

It's obviously not finished, but I was wondering, let's say there was an 'a' and an 'e', how would I replace both of them in the same statement?

Answer (score 3):

Why not:

```
import re

text = 'hello world'
res = re.sub('([aeiou])', r'\1f\1', text)
# hefellofo woforld
```

Comment: This is a better approach than mine, +1

Answer (score 1):

```
line = input('Line: ')
line = line.replace('a', 'afa')
line = line.replace('e', 'efe')
line = line.replace('i', 'ifi')
line = line.replace('o', 'ofo')
line = line.replace('u', 'ufu')
print(line)
```

Got it!

Answer (score 1):

> let's say there was an 'a' and an 'e', how would I replace both of them in the same statement?

You can chain the `replace()` calls:

```
print(line.replace('a', 'afa').replace('e', 'efe'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string = 'abcdefghij'
replace_objects = {'a' : 'b', 'c' : 'd'}
for key in replace_objects:
    mystring = mystring.replace(key, replace_objects[key])
```

If you've got a load of replacements to do and you want to populate the replacement list after a while it's quite easy with a dictionary. Altho regexp or `re` is prefered.